# Не срабатывает валидация формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма с кнопкой отправки заявки

И js обработчик

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').submit(function() {
    if (document.form.name.value == '' || document.form.phone.value == '' ||
      document.form.theme.value == '' ||
      doctype.form.text.value == '') {
      valid = false;
      return valid;
      alert('error');
    }
    $.ajax({ // отправка данных на почту через php файл
      type: "POST",
      url: "shop/mail/mail.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() { // сброс фомы и вызов обработчика результата отправки
      $('.js-overlay-thank-you').fadeIn();
      $(this).find('input').val('');
      $('#form').trigger('reset');
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" name="form" id="form">
  <input type="text" class="form-filed" name="name" placeholder=" Имя">
  <input type="text" class="form-filed" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
  <input type="text" class="form-filed" name="theme" placeholder="Тема">
  <textarea name="text" class="form-filed" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>
  <button class="form-button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

При вводе не всех данный в форму обработчик не срабатывает и отправляет незаполненную форму.
В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

```
doctype.form.text.value == '') {
```

Откуда тут `doctype` взялось?

Вряд ли Ваш `alert` выполнится после `return`.

```
  alert('error');
  return valid;
```

Comment: Спасибо,два часа искал ошибку, а она была в опечатке)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй вместо || использовать &&

Comment: Зачем? Вдруг сработает?